# NixOS - How to configure config property which is a type of types.lines

Tags: nix, nixos

Tried to install Flexget. On the Options website it shows that there is `config` defined [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/3a9e0f239d80fa134e8fcbdee4dfc793902da37e/nixos/modules/services/torrent/flexget.nix#L47)

How does it work? it says the type is `types.lines`. Tried to write some random text, but the config file is not created and the daemon fails to start.

Edit:

So here is my configs inside `configuration.nix`:

```hs
  services.flexget = {
    enable = true;
    config = "asdas\n asdas";
  };
```

and when I run `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` this is what happens:

```
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
NOT restarting the following changed units: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-FuHua.service, systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-25A4\x2d32EA.service
activating the configuration...
setting up /etc...
reloading user units for shalva...
setting up tmpfiles
reloading the following units: dbus.service
the following new units were started: flexget-runner.timer, flexget.service
warning: the following units failed: flexget-runner.service

× flexget-runner.service - FlexGet Runner
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flexget-runner.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-04-28 10:34:20 UTC; 129ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● flexget-runner.timer
    Process: 92136 ExecStart=/nix/store/1pdq67nfjw2mad5s679dfgm5h98bm4xm-flexget-3.1.153/bin/flexget -c /var/lib/deluge/flexget.yml execute (code=exited, status=217/USER)
   Main PID: 92136 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
         IP: 0B in, 0B out
        CPU: 799us

Apr 28 10:34:20 Lenovo-7200 systemd[1]: Started FlexGet Runner.
Apr 28 10:34:20 Lenovo-7200 systemd[92136]: flexget-runner.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Apr 28 10:34:20 Lenovo-7200 systemd[92136]: flexget-runner.service: Failed at step USER spawning /nix/store/1pdq67nfjw2mad5s679dfgm5h98bm4xm-flexget-3.1.153/bin/flexget: No such process
Apr 28 10:34:20 Lenovo-7200 systemd[1]: flexget-runner.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Apr 28 10:34:20 Lenovo-7200 systemd[1]: flexget-runner.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
warning: error(s) occurred while switching to the new configuration
```

I htink the problem is in `/nix/store/1pdq67nfjw2mad5s679dfgm5h98bm4xm-flexget-3.1.153/bin/flexget -c /var/lib/deluge/flexget.yml`. Because the config file is not created. here is the output of it:

```
shalva in Lenovo-7200 in ~ took 16s
❯ /nix/store/1pdq67nfjw2mad5s679dfgm5h98bm4xm-flexget-3.1.153/bin/flexget -c /var/lib/deluge/flexget.yml
Could not instantiate manager: Config `/var/lib/deluge/flexget.yml` does not appear to be a file.
```

my expectation is that `config = "asdas\n asdas";` should at least create config file at `/var/lib/deluge/flexget.yml`, right? I know it will still fail because it wont be valid config, but at least it should be created...

Comment: Could you provide some more detail, like the relevant part of your configuration and any logs from the service? And just to be sure, forgive me: did you set the `services.flexget.enable` option to `true`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, I have updated the questions. yes, I do have `enable = true;`

Comment: According to the [source file responsible for this option](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-unstable/nixos/modules/services/torrent/flexget.nix), the config file is indeed created at `"${services.flexget.homeDir}/flexget.yml"`. By default, `services.flexget.homeDir` is `/var/lib/deluge`, so the file should be created at the right place. Please check you haven't overwritten `services.flexget.homeDir`. I think you can even check what is its final value with `nixos-option` (you have to install it, it's not bundled in by default).

Answer (score 0):

Flexget is a software which is meant to be run together with deluge, therefore it expects the user `deluge` and its home directory to be available. The service will not create the user `deluge` by itself.

Enable deluge and flexget will start up correctly:

```
services.deluge.enable = true;
services.deluge.package = pkgs.deluge-2_x;
```

If you want to only run flexget without deluge you need to have the directory created and either change the flexget user and create the user deluge by hand.